# Odd Space forming on top of HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am creating a column chart with Google Charts API->http://plnkr.co/edit/GTg6MfMephB8lR3Kp66S?p=preview

but for some reason an odd space is forming on top of the page.

This started happening after I changed the Material Chart library :

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

and used a classic chart instead (I need it since the Material Library is not complete and it doesn't allow custom Tooltips):

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
```

This is the original Material Chart -> http://plnkr.co/edit/dMVKt3ISlMtyiYmVeN1K?p=preview

What's wrong?

Comment: something is wrong with your SVG height i reckon .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add settings for the chart area, for example:

```
chartArea: { width: '100%', height: '99%' },
```

or:

```
chartArea: { left: 0, top: 30, width: 1200, height: 5450 },
```

Comment: @CrisBenois: No, the 1% difference in the height or the 30 pixel top offset makes room for the title.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack but the below will "sort it"...

```
#columnchart_material{margin-top:-500px}
```

Can't quite work out why it's happening in the first place though?

Comment: In your CSS, depends if you are doing it inline or externallyy?